# Value position in calculated vector from subset data

Tags: r, dataframe, position, subset, indices

I've been searching everywhere for this and I haven't yet found a useful answer:

I have an initial dataframe:

```
> Ty <- c("c","v","c","c","v","v","c","c")
> y <- runif(8)
> x1 <- runif(8)
> x2 <- runif(8)
> x3 <- runif(8)
> df <- data.frame(Ty,y,x1,x2,x3)
> df
  Ty          y        x1        x2        x3
1  c 0.20837948 0.9990686 0.6081206 0.4800121
2  v 0.98047271 0.8098506 0.3377099 0.2677663
3  c 0.11320570 0.8201667 0.6102719 0.7521935
4  c 0.78059215 0.9227924 0.8973975 0.9731085
5  v 0.42921617 0.4732868 0.5234706 0.8788630
6  v 0.88079516 0.2566475 0.9642301 0.2265124
7  c 0.08974227 0.6505454 0.8664035 0.6288450
8  c 0.99710543 0.3626812 0.2148892 0.3996121
```

I need to use only the data with Type="C", so I proceed to subset it:

```
> df.c <- subset(df,Ty=="c")
> df.c
  Ty          y        x1        x2        x3
1  c 0.20837948 0.9990686 0.6081206 0.4800121
3  c 0.11320570 0.8201667 0.6102719 0.7521935
4  c 0.78059215 0.9227924 0.8973975 0.9731085
7  c 0.08974227 0.6505454 0.8664035 0.6288450
8  c 0.99710543 0.3626812 0.2148892 0.3996121
```

Note that the position index is preserved from the original matrix  `df`. After subsetting my `df` matrix, I needed to build a regression model:

```
> reg <- lm(y~x1+x2+x3, data = df.c)
> pred <- predict(reg, df.c)
> pred
        1         3         4         7         8 
0.1020748 0.5735144 0.4673496 0.2027020 0.8433842
```

After calling `pred` it shows the original position indices (1,3,4,7,8), but when I call the index position I need, for example `pred[3]` wanting to get the value `0.5735144`, it gives me instead the value in the third position `0.4673496`:

```
> pred[3]
        4 
0.4673496
```

How can I access to the position index I need, brought from the original `df` matrix, in this case, position `3`?

Comment: `pred[3]` is looking for  value at position 3. Instead what you call `original position indices (1,3,4,7,8)` are not indexes anymore, they are names for vector elements. Maybe you want `pred[names(pred)=="3"]` to get `0.5735144`

Comment: Or just `pred["3"]`.

Comment: Just get rid of the bad names that don't line up: `pred = unname(pred)`. For exactly cases like this it's bad to rely on integer row names.

Comment: Thank you everyone! really simple but enormously helpful!

Comment: I have another problem related to this topic, if you can give me a quick hand with it. What if I need to get rid of that value `pred["3"]` ?  I've tried  `pred[-"3"]`getting an error. Is there a way of doing it without having to create a new data frame?

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by @JilberUrbina in a comment, the row names/names of the vector returned by `predict()` are actually a *character vector*, so `pred["3"]` should get what you want.

- If `p` is an integer, indexing by `pred[p]` gives you the pth element in the vector;
- if `p` is a character (**but not a factor**!), `pred[p]` gives you the element that has a *name* that matches the contents of `p`.

If you want to *remove* a value indexed by character, you have to use this (fairly clunky) idiom:

```
p[names(p) != "3"]
```

i.e. `p[-"3"]` doesn't work ...

Comment: Just checked, if `p` is a factor it will be treated as an integer and its level number will be used, not the label. E.g., `p = factor("Datsun 710"); mtcars[p, ]` returns the first row, "Mazda RX4".

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer, neally helpful. I have another problem related to this topic, if you can give me a quick hand with it. What if I need to get rid of that value pred["3"] ? I've tried pred[-"3"]getting an error. Is there a way of doing it without having to create a new data frame?